# When/why would you use Linq in an application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i know how linq works but i am not getting idea where exactly i should use linq?

Comment: LINQ is used for data binding to a database to simplify SQL queries.

Comment: @invalidsyntax - not quite, that's only LINQ-to-SQL, a subset/extension of LINQ.

Comment: @invalidsyntax  correct but incomplete.. it not only supports querying on databases but event Collections, XML, and many more

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know that. Thank you for clarifying for me. You learn something new each day :)

Comment: Geez, everyone jumped on this.  Are we talking about LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Objects?  If LINQ to Objects, then when wouldn't you?  It's much easier to search your collections with LINQ.

Comment: At places where it makes code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 12):

The question is rather like asking "*I know how plus and minus work, but when do I use addition? When do I use subtraction?*"

You use addition when you want to know the sum of two things and subtraction when you want to know their difference.

Essentially all LINQ does is add operators to the C# and VB languages for sorting, filtering, projecting, joining and grouping. When do you use LINQ? When you want to sort, filter, project, join or group something.

Comment: thanks.that is the use ,but does it suitable for multi tire application

Comment: @Vporecha: I do not understand your question.

Comment: @Vporecha: Your question is irrelevant as to whether or not it is suitable. LINQ is perfectly fine to use in a mult-tier application. What makes you think it wouldn't be suitable?

Comment: i just want to know ,as i want to use it.well thats why it makes me think.

Answer (score 6):

I say use LINQ.. *Absolutely anywhere* that it will help accomplish your goal in a concise and maintainable way.

There is no broad use or don't use restrictions, you really have to make a judgement for the piece of code at hand to whether or not it will benefit from LINQ, in general some of the old overly verbose pieces of code (nested looping etc) can be more clearly expressed in LINQ and might be beneficial.

And it should be noted that LINQ is **NOT** synonymous with LINQ to SQL, LINQ stands for Language Integrated Query and is extraordinarily useful outside a database context.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is used generally when you have to work with IEnumerable (or IQueryable in case of operations against a database). **It makes your code cleaner and more functional.**

You could use it for example to replace a for loop:

```
from i in Enumerable.Range(0, n)
where i % 2 == 0
select i;
```

instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        something.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use LINQ where you find it appropriate -because it can be both more expressive/concise than conventional common procedural programming idioms.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize it for a number of scenarios, e.g:

- Retrieving data from Entity Framework or using Linq to SQL
- Perform operations on collections (sorting, selecting, etc)
- Traversing XML documents

These operations all require significantly less code using Linq.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is a standard. Custom layers you make are not, not unless your team pre-built and agreed upon a custom layer. If your team won't make custom layers, then using LINQ might alleviate the problem of each people having their own way of making requests to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you want to filter data within your application without having to run a query.  Here's a good place to look at examples of how you may want to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For me it makes my code more concise and easier to maintain. use it anywhere you have to work with accessing or manipulting Collection of data like Databases, XML, Lists, etc.

But just keep in mind some of it quirks.

Answer (score 0):

At places where it makes code more **readable** and **maintainable**.

In places where you work with collections of data and you want to **transform, filter, connect or sort it**.

You do **not have to** use LINQ, it is not the cure for all problems. It may actually perform worse than the procedual programmed way in some cases.

Start using it and with the **time and experience** you get the feeling where it makes sense and is most useful.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answer.
the answer might take pages why linq? but in short after reading ceratin books,
if i say The main goal of LINQ and LINQ to SQL is to
get rid of, or at least reduce An impedance mismatch between Relational database structure and object oriented . it’s easier to adapt the C#  language than to change SQL or XML.
With LINQ, the aim is toward deeply integrating the capabilities of data query and
manipulation languages into programming languages.
LINQ removes many of the barriers among objects, databases, and XML. It
enables us to work with each of these paradigms using the same language-integrated
facilities.

i got answer from book **Linq In Action. **
in this first chapter clears why linq.
this is really good book.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example. You want to write a simple query that retrieves customers as follows:

```
SELECT UPPER(Name)
FROM Customer
WHERE Name LIKE 'A%'
ORDER BY Name
```

That doesn't look too bad, right? But now suppose these results are feeding a web page, and we want to retrieve just rows 21-30. Suddenly, you need a subquery:

```
SELECT UPPER(Name) FROM
(
   SELECT *, RN = row_number()
   OVER (ORDER BY Name)
   FROM Customer
   WHERE Name LIKE 'A%'
) A
WHERE RN BETWEEN 21 AND 30
ORDER BY Name
```

Here's same query in LINQ. The gain in simplicity is clear:

```
var query =
   from c in db.Customers
   where c.Name.StartsWith ("A")
   orderby c.Name
   select c.Name.ToUpper();

var thirdPage = query.Skip(20).Take(10);
```

Only when we enumerate thirdPage will the query actually execute. In the case of LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework, the translation engine will convert the query (that we composed in two steps) into a single SQL statement optimized for the database server to which it's connected.